# JSON file is not read from level of subdirectories using jquery function getJSON() or post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

JSON file is not read from level of subdirectories using jquery function getJSON() or $.post() on change event of dropdownbox

I given the file path that is get dynamically

```
DIRECTORY PATH = /home/spipl8/www/football/wallpaper/spg.wallpaper.artem.dzyuba.football/more.json
```

script.js

```
$(document).on("change","#dir_list",function(){
        var dir_val = $(this).val();
        console.log(dir_val+"/more.json");
        //return false;
        $.getJSON(dir_val+"/more.json",function(data){
            var list='';
            console.log(data);
            /*for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                list +='<li class="img_contain"><div class="box"><img src="'+data[i]['img']+'" key="'+i+'" ply_name="'+data[i]['name']+'" path="'+data[i]['path']+'"></div><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove" key="'+i+'"><img src="assets/images/delete.png"></a><label class="player_name">'+data[i]['name']+'</label></li>';
            }
            $("#sortable").html(list);*/
        });
    }); 

    more.json
    [
{"name":"Artem Dzyuba","img":"\/home\/spipl8\/www\/football\/wallpaper\/spg.wallpaper.artem.dzyuba.football\/thumb\/artem_dzyuba_0707_0015.jpg","path":"spg.wallpaper.artem.dzyuba.football"},
{"name":"Emil Forsberg","img":"\/","path":"spg.wallpaper.emil.forsberg.football"},{"name":"Gilanluigi Buffon","img":"\/home\/spipl8\/www\/football\/wallpaper\/spg.wallpaper.gilanluigi.buffon.football\/thumb\/buffon_0630_0047.jpg","path":"spg.wallpaper.gilanluigi.buffon.football"}
]
```

Comment: You run site from folder (local) or from server? If from server, then type path to more.json file in browserser and check that it is reachable in this way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running this JS file locally, you should have in consideration where you are running it. What **you are passing** to $.getJSON **is a relative path**, **not an absolute path**.

So, if your JS file is in the directory '/abc' then the getJSON will check on "/abc/home/spipl8/www/football/wallpaper/spg.wallpaper.artem.dzyuba.football/more.json"